# Ruby on Rails - MySql POINT type

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, geolocation, point

I have a model with one POINT typed attribute. (MySql)
How can I set model attribute through active record?

Im looking for something like I did in yii2:

```
$coordStr = 'POINT('.$object->latitude.' '.$object->longitude.')';
$object->coord = new yii\db\Expression("GeomFromText(:coord)", array(':coord' => $coordStr));
```

Comment: Have you solved it? I need this answer too.

Comment: Hello, yes, I've solved. I could send you a code on Monday, is it ok?

Comment: It's ok, I have sorted it out. I'm using ActiveRecord's adapter `mysql2rgeo`.